# thread pause and resume

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a multithreaded program. I want start the new `BackgroundWorker` and pause the current thread. Then I want resume previous thread in the new `BackgroundWorker`.
I am programming in C#.

I have a big project and cannot put my code here.

Comment: What are you trying to do that "Pause a thread then continue on a new thread" is your desired outcome?

Comment: If your main thread pauses until the BackgroundWorker has finished you might as well do the work in your main thread

Comment: I want show progressBar with cancel button.
when progerssBar start all controls disabled. but cancel button be enable. and ...

Comment: @sharafi your progressBar will freeze if you pause the UI thread. Disabling controlls is a whole different thing. BackgroundWorker is the right way to go in that case and I think hicurins answer explains how to use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my sample code for you! I'm not so sure it useful for your project, but this is my idea. hope helpful.

```
 BackgroundWorker bwExportLogFile = new BackgroundWorker();

        private void ExportLogFile() {
            bwExportLogFile.DoWork += bwExportLogFile_DoWork;
            bwExportLogFile.RunWorkerCompleted += bwExportLogFile_RunWorkerCompleted;
            bwExportLogFile.ProgressChanged += bwExportLogFile_ProgressChanged;
            bwExportLogFile.RunWorkerAsync();
            bwExportLogFile.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bwExportLogFile.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        }

        void bwExportLogFile_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            if(some thing is true here){
                bw.CancelAsync();
            }
        }
```

So when you want to run thread in BackgroundWorker again just call this:

```
bwExportLogFile.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: when you call it again, because bwExportLogFile is a global variable.

Comment: when I call bwExportLogFile.RunWorkerAsync(); current thread is pause?

Comment: No, when you call bw.CancelAsync(); on ProgressChanged event current thread is paused. And when you call bwExportLogFile.RunWorkerAsync(); I think thread run again. Let try it

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd6a283y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use [WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.waitone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to hold the parent thread. Call [AutoResetEvent.Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/cc452330) method from spawned thread to resume the execution of parent (main) thread.

```
childThread.Start();
autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
```

In child (spawned thread)

```
private void SpawnedThread()
{
      //your code
     autoResetEvent.Set(); //will resume the execution after WaitOne(), may be under some condition.
}
```

You can use [overloaded version of WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to give the maximum wait time. The execution will resume of Set method is not being called until the give time.

Comment: When autoResetEvent.Set(); is called from other thread or wait time is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set WorkerSupportsCancellation = true and in ProgressChanged event you can do like this:

```
 BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
 bw.CancelAsync();
 bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: please more explanation